# Bash script to check if service is running

Tags: bash

I have written up the following script

```
#! /bin/bash
function checkIt()
{
 ps auxw | grep $1 | grep -v grep > /dev/null

 if [ $? != 0 ]
 then
   echo $1"bad";
 else
   echo $1"good";
 fi;
}

checkIt "nginx";
checkIt "mysql";
checkIt "php5-fpm";
```

The problem here appears to be with the last check `checkIt "php5-fpm"` which consistently returns php5-fpmbad.  The trouble appears to arise due to the hyphen.  If I do just `checkIt "php5"` I get the expected result.  I could actually get away with it since I do not have any other process that starts with or contains php5.  However, it turns into a hack that will rear up its ugly head one day.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me how to  get checkIt "php5-fpm" to work.

Comment: you realize that if you run application with command line `vi nginx.xml` your script is going to think nginx is running?

Comment: Once again - the comment is pretty much orthogonal to my question.

Comment: Probably make no difference but you should really quote `"$1"`

Comment: If someone else on the machine is running a command like `vim nginx-instructions.txt`, your function would report that nginx is running, whether or not it actually is. Don't reinvent the many service monitoring programs that already exist.

Answer (score 9):

The normal way to check if service is running or not in *nix is by executing this:

```
/etc/init.d/servicename status
```

e.g.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqls status
```

These scripts check status by PID rather than grepping ps output.

Comment: this is correct for linux where the application is actually registered as a service like it should be, for other environment that have `bash`, like OSX for example, this would not be the correct solution.

Comment: @Oleg Mikheev I have downvoted your answer.  If I had wanted to know "How do I check the status of a running process" I would have asked that question. You have answered an entirely different question.  If you must know  - I am not using `etc/init.d/proc status` or `service proc status` because the answer that is returned is not consistent.  Most often it is `proc is running` but, for instance, php5-fpm returns `php5-fpm start/running` or `php5-fpm stop/waiting`

Comment: To be fair to Oleg, you actually did ask the question "Bash script to check if service is running", and Oleg answered exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

Add word boundaries and a negative *lookahead* `regex` to your `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
function checkIt()
{
 ps auxw | grep -P '\b'$1'(?!-)\b' >/dev/null
 if [ $? != 0 ]
 then
   echo $1"bad";
 else
   echo $1"good";
 fi;
}

checkIt "nginx"
checkIt "mysql"
checkIt "php5-fpm"
```

Comment: What difference does this make ?